# Лимит на отправку сообщений

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Помогите пожалуйста сделать лимит на отправку сообщений с формы сайта. Например user может отправить только 10 сообщений после этого будет ошибка: Отдохните! Подождите 7 минут, и можете снова отправлять сообщения

Comment: как раз только что обсуждали, готовый пример смотрите тут http://stackoverflow.com/a/5031515/3993065 осталось дописать обработку 10 сообщений.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Уточните: пользователи всегда авторизованы или анонимны? Сообщения отправляются ajax'ом или обычным POST'ом с переходом на страницу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

самое простое - писать в куки счетчик, и при привышении не разрешать. но опять таки почистил куки - и может писать, возможно считывать ip человека и писать счетчик в базу, но тоже не лучший вариант

Answer (score 0):

Можно создавать уникальный ключ: выдавать его при загрузке страницы и хранить на сервере. При отправке сообщения прикрепляется и этот ключ.

Получив сообщение с ключем, сервер проверяет, есть ли такой ключ у него. Если есть – принимать сообщение и инкрементировать ассоциированный с ним счетчик. В ответ отдавать новый ключ.

Обходится это новым свежим заходом на страницу с получением ключа как будто новый пользователь.

Авторизация пользователей снимает эту проблему, привязывая счётчик к аккаунту.

Answer (score 0):

В сессии сохранять число отправок. При превышении блокировать. Полагаю, сессия живёт дольше этих 7 минут, так что всё должно быть хорошо.